# Can't play video in gallery

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6

The phone I am using is a Samsung galaxy s6 edge with the latest software installed.

One I have recorded a video of some sort, I go to the gallery to check what the video is like. As I click on the video a message comes quoting "Can't play video." I have looked around some say that the file is corrupted, some say it is the video player I am using (Gallery) etc. Pictures are completely fine, my guess is videos are in the wrong format?

Anyone have a guess as to what the problem is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I had to uninstall Google+ updates to fix this.

Comment: I can't really see how two are related?